# How to Load Text file into Hbase in Linux Machine

Tags: hadoop, hbase

How to load text file which is i my local machine to a remote Hbase. I refered the above command but i am really confused with the command

```
hadoop jar <path to hbase jar> importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=a,b,c '-Dimporttsv.separator=,' <tablename> <inputdir>
```

Where to address the path of the text file and table name and columns will be in text file.
In text file i has the create and put statements, how to load and execute that file in Hbase  shell. Please break my confusion if any 1 knows it.

Script File:

```
create 'blogpostss', 'post', 'image' 

Run in HBase shell the following to add some data:

put 'blogpostss', 'post1', 'post:title', 'Hello World'
put 'blogpostss', 'post1', 'post:author', 'The Author'
put 'blogpostss', 'post1', 'post:body', 'This is a blog post'
put 'blogpostss', 'post1', 'image:header', 'image1.jpg'
put 'blogpostss', 'post1', 'image:bodyimage', 'image2.jpg'

put 'blogpostss', 'post2', 'post:title', 'Another Post'
put 'blogpostss', 'post2', 'post:title', 'My Second Post'

put 'blogpostss', 'post1', 'post:body', 'This is an updated blog postss'

Following commands retrieve data:

get 'blogpostss', 'post1'
get 'blogpostss', 'post1', { COLUMN => 'post:title' }
get 'blogpostss', 'post1', { COLUMN => 'post:title', VERSIONS => 4 }
get 'blogpostss', 'post1', { COLUMNS => 'post:body', VERSIONS => 3 }

get 'blogpostss', 'post2'
get 'blogpostss', 'post2', { COLUMN => 'post:title' }
get 'blogpostss', 'post2', { COLUMN => 'post:title', VERSIONS => 4 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Use terminal and ssh to the desired hbase configured Pc. 
2.Copy your local text file to HDFS.
3.create a table with desired column family using Hbase shell.
4.Now execute your command to insert..
`hadoop jar <path to hbase jar> importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=a,b,c '-Dimporttsv.separator=,' <tablename> <inputdir>`

NOTE:
 
     path to hbase jar -> Path, where the hbase jar is available.
     tablename -> table name which you created now.
     inputdir  -> fully qualified Hdfs path with file extention.
     -Dimporttsv.columns=a,b,c -> column family:qualifer has to mention.

Comment: In my Text File there are number of create statments are there. Its SOmething like SQL Script. So In the Command How can i declare a table name and column name.So How can i execute the script according. Please check my script file as above

Comment: how your text file will look like? give two lines as sample.

Comment: Please view the above link, I have posted my  Text File.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092741/how-to-load-text-file-into-hbase-in-linux-machine/12103719#comment16234768_12103719]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1) Do ssh to your hbase machine

2) copy that file to below path:

```
/home/hbase/hbase-0.98.3-hadoop2/bin (it can be change according to where you have hbase folder)
```

3)[root@hostname bin]# ./hbase shell ./sample_commands.txt